# Bas Cohen having relations with a non-Jew

Tags: halacha, gentiles, kohen-priest, baal-teshuva, pidyon-haben

It says in SA YD Siman 305 that a Bas Cohen that has a bechor (firstborn) with a non-Jew there is chiyuv of pidyon haben since the Bas Cohen through having relations with the non-Jew she looses her status of being a Bas Cohen. What about if a not-frum (irreligious) Bas Cohen before becoming a baalas teshuva (religious person) had relations with a non-Jew. Then after becoming frum (religious) later got married to a Yisrael and had a bechor. Is there a chiyuv of making a pidyon haben on that child? (My doubt is because through the relations with the non-Jew before becoming frum perhaps she lost her status of being a Bas Cohen.)

Comment: In [Yalkut Yossef][1], it wrotes in sayif 34 that the child will be chayav of pidion.
However, he wrote in sayif 26 that a woman can lie on her past for chalom bayit and not said that the child is not her first one.


  [1]: http://yalkut.info/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A8/%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA.htm

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/929263/jewish/Who.htm#footnoteRef1a929263

Answer (score 7):

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 134:9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49256&pgnum=211) clearly indicates that a Bas Kohain who has had relations with a non Jew prior to having a child with a Jew would do a Pidyon HaBen as the relationship is what makes her a Chalal.

[Shach Yoreh Deah 305:22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=272) also says that a Bas Kohain who has had relations with a non Jew prior to having a child with a Jew would do a Pidyon HaBen.

Answer (score -2):

A kohen's daughter does not lose her status as a kohen's daughter by simply having pre-marital sex; she loses it through either marrying a non-kohen or through having his baby. In the event that she marries him and then has a divorce, so long as she was never pregnant she regains her former status and all of its privileges.

Comment: You're conflating having a baby with being pregnant: do you know which of them is the relevant criterion? And do you have a source for the answer, please?

Comment: If she is pregnant for more than forty days it makes no difference if she miscarries later, any subsequent son will not be a *bechor*. There are plenty of sources; I apologise for the fact that I've not the time to source them now. I'm not writing an answer for the points, but merely for the purposes of responding. When I've time I'll edit my answer and add some.

Comment: If she has a child with a non-kohein and then the child dies many years later, she still reverts back to being a bat kohein for terumah.